# How to Import and Show String and Image from SQLiteDB to a custom ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-sqlite

How do I import a Table contains 3 columns id,name and image from a SQLite Database to a custom ListView 
Ihope the answer to be detailed
Notice : I'm a beginner so take it easy on me :D and sorry if my English is bad

Comment: You can't just ask of how to write entire application. What have you tried so far, and what **exactly** is a problem?

Comment: https://github.com/joancolmenerodev/SQLiteExample change the variables and you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 db = openOrCreateDatabase("sms.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    Cursor cc = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM datatable", null);
    final ArrayList<DataModel> row1 = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cc != null) {
        cc.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < cc.getCount(); i++) {

            String id = cc.getString(0);
            String name = cc.getString(1);
            String image = cc.getString(2);
            DataModel datamodel = new Datamodel();
            datamodel.setid(id);
            datamodel.setname(name);
            datamodel.setimage(image);
            row1.add(datamodel);
            cc.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

or you can get values by name
cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("name"));